# Leaflet Shifted tiles

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to display an multible large images in tiles with leafletjs. 
I got all these images and already sliced them into tiles. But when i display them in Leaflet there is some weird zoom.
The Rectangle is Drawn by my JS and stays on the same Coordinates. So my question is, is this a bug within leaflet or my Tile algorithm.

On Zoom 6:
[image: Zoom 6]

On Zoom 5:
[image: Zoom 5]

On Zoom 4:
[image: Zoom 4]

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. But Leaflet is pretty reliable, so you might check first on your tiles. You could also give a shot to Open Layers to make sure.

Comment: I tracked it down to the Slicing function. It seems like a problem with the calculation of the width of each tile as the image is not square. When using a fixed Resulution like 512x512 for an image that has 4958x7017 the image will be stretched so the function tires to alter the Resolution but that is not correct. Do you know any algorithm to calculate a Resolution for Non- Rectangular images/ Tiles?

Comment: You should have software and libraries that can do that for you (MapTiler, zoomify…). Feel free to open a new question on that topic if needed.